# Accessing the Windows Application Data settings from Embarcadero C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder

I have an Embarcadero C++Builder project, and I want to read/write some app data.

The research I found tells me to use code such as the following:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =    
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

My question is: What namespace/library do I need to include, to use this code?

As it stands, I get the following compiler error:

```
E2070 Invalid use of namespace 'Windows'
```

I tried to include Windows namespace:

```
using namespace Windows;
```

This did not get rid of the compiler error.

I tried the following:

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
```

But get the following compiler error:

```
E2316 'Storage' is not a member of 'Windows'
```

Can anyone throw some light on this (very basic) question?

Comment: try `System.SysUtils.GetHomePath` this appears to be the correct place to store app data. (eg appdata on windows) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.GetHomePath

Comment: You can't use WinRT APIs in C++Builder projects.  To determine the path of special OS folders, use the Win32 API [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) functions.  Internally, [`System::Sysutils::GetHomePath()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.GetHomePath) calls `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)` on Windows.